# Excel Conditional Statement - 2 cells equal keep 1 based on value of another

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Hi I am looking for help writing an if statement in excel. I have a data set containing zip codes, and a residing/adjacent column. I would like to create a new column that contains either blanks, keep, remove based on the below conditions.

My current statement works for the 'keep' but does nothing else =IF(D2=B2,IF(F2= "Residing", "Keep", "Discard"),"")  Below is some sample data.
Possibilities:

1. two zips do not match and adjacent (wont ever be residing) - new column would be blank (eg row 3)
2. Two zips match and residing but also have matches that are adjacent- want those to be keep (eg row 1)
3. Two zips match and = adjacent but also have a residing match- want those to be labeled "remove" (eg row 2)

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When do you want remove? When do you want discard? Maybe provide all possibilities as a list (and not an uninterrupted paragraph) and make sure you cover all of them. Also, what does "...and have more than value for adjacent/residing" mean?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I updated the  post. What I meant by your last part is for instance 42045 has 3 row, want to label "Keep" to the row that is residing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,C2="Adjacent",COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,"Residing")>0),"Remove",IF(AND(A2=B2,C2="Residing"),"Keep",""))
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works on this subset, however when I apply to a larger scale only the "keep" works, I am guessing it has something to do with formatting, do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: There's no reason I can think of for it not to work on more data. My suggestion is to carefully audit a row you believe should return "remove". Note that the formula doesn't care whether or not the "residing" row (to keep) is next to the adjacent row(s) (to remove).